# Changing the “Double Arrow” image used by SharePoints WebPart Connections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, connected-web-parts

How do I Change the “**Double Arrow**” image used in SharePoint's WebPart Connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a way please see  below.

```
 <style>
IMG[src*='/_layouts/15/images/rbsel.gif'] {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png');
    WIDTH: 26px;
    HEIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 26px
}
IMG[src*='/_layouts/15/images/rbunsel.gif'] {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png');
    WIDTH: 26px;
    HEIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 26px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this might be the optimize solution.
You can write a jquery get the double arrow image and replace it with custom image. 
E.g:

```
Get all image with double arrow on the page
 var collection =$('img[src$="rbsel.gif"]');
//loop it
$.each(collection,function(index,item){
  //replace the image src here
$(item).src(tosomething);
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i was browsing through this link but cant seems to get it to work as i havent worked with content editor should it work with script editor instead https://brenthafnersblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/changing-the-double-arrow-image-used-by-sharepoints-webpart-connections/

Comment: i have added the below code to the script editor bit its not working <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var collection =$('img[src$="rbsel.gif"]');
//loop it
$.each(collection,function(index,item){
  //replace the image src here
$(item).src('"https://kk.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FSiteOffices%2FSiteAssets%2Fradio%2Dbutton%2Dselected%2Egif&parent=%2Fsites%2FSiteOffices%2FSiteAssets");
});
</script>

Comment: Is it giving any error. Check whether you are getting list of element in collection  variable